# Recommend crossplatform C++ UI and networking libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, wxwidgets

Things to take into consideration:
- easy to use
- fast
- use underlying OS as much as feasable (like wxWidgets for UI)

Ones I am leaning towards are wxWidgets for UI and Boost for networking - how do they compare to others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had good look with wxWidgets on the front end and boost::asio on the network end.

wxWidgets does have network classes built in, but you hit the wall quickly on them, and there's one or two big limitations. If you want to stay in the wx world, there's a package called [wxCurl](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/wxcurl/) which is a fine package (I used it in the early days) that wraps libCurl with some wxWidgets idomatic C++.

In a previous project of mine (a network/file transfer heavy project) we ended up going with boost::asio, which had the advantage of not being all that hard of an API, easier-seeming to set up that libCRUL (although that may have gotten better, that was been several years now), and gives us a very generic networking core (boost can compile anywhere, even command line apps)

Comment: NO! Don't use wxCurl! Use libcurl directly. Take my advice: wxCurl has its share of bugs.

Answer (score 11):

I hear good things about [qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) for GUI

> Qt is a cross-platform application and
>   UI framework. Using Qt, you can write
>   web-enabled applications once and
>   deploy them across desktop, mobile and
>   embedded operating systems without
>   rewriting the source code

Comment: I would point out that QT is not c++. The addition of moc means it is a new language (an extension to c++). That said, it _is_ a nice graphics lib.

Comment: QT is very robust but licensing may be an issue... Stick to wxWidgets.

Comment: QT is a good answer, but is previously mentioned, it's not C++ and for the UI it defines it's own look (it was part of my question to be as close to the OS as possible). Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: QT UI uses native OS graphics where possible. You can write custom widgets in any case. And although it's not "technically" C++, in practice, you're writing C++. Certainly in the parts of your app that don't touch QT.

Comment: Two reasons why I didn't pick that as an answer - as mentioned above, it's not C++ and in my experience isn't using OS UI (it defines its own in a lot of cases). It is also a bit of a behemoth, compared to wxWidgets I think. I was interested to find if there were other libraries like wxWidgets (perhaps better ones) - not interested in bigger libraries like QT, GTK, etc. For what I was after, they are outside the scope of what I needed. 

Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For GUI I would strongly recommend using Qt. It is very powerful GUI framework that requires writing very few lines of code. It has very nice and easy to use model of signals and slots.

`wxWidgets` IMHO too modeled after MFC which has very bad model.

Networking: I would suggest go for `Boost.Asio` very powerful and nice. However if you
want to integrate networking to GUI main loop you may try to use Qt classes for that, however I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [XVT](http://www.xvt.com) historically, which has been used commercially by thousands of companies.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) can do networking even if it's not their first goal.

For more network centric libraries, apart from [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), you can check [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) (Adaptative Communication
Environment ) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comparisons between these libraries have [already been discussed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ACE+boost+POCO).

Comment: Yes... actually if you are doing HTTP/FTP stuff, stay away from the wxWidgets classes for this. Use libcurl. It's cross-platform too.

Comment: I think the documentation of boost::asio is extremely poor. I would stick with qt and it's networking module. The Qt documentations is the best I ever read.

Answer (score 0):

boost::asio seems to be very well written, and has a very clean API -- I am still trying to learn how well it is for shared-nothing [multithreaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325043/boostasio-thread-local-asynchronous-events) TCP/IP.

Your other choices might be [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), or [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). Poco's socket abstraction is quite naive --i.e., it only allows the Poco way of doing things. I've never heard anything good about ACE.

**edit:** Hmm, I'm re-examining ACE and its making more sense to me now (after having written a few networking apps) -- it might be suitable for my needs compared to ASIO. However, it is more than likely overkill for you. If my peers find out about this, I will be shunned till the end of time.

Answer (score 0):

We have had good success using wxWidgets with boost::asio, both recommended for desktop-server development.

Answer (score 0):

For GUI, I can recommend QT

For Networking ACE (Adaptive Communication Environment) or boost::asio.